# changing forms of constant of integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In solving O.D.E in my book sometimes he changes the constant of integration in the form for example C=Sin(A) where C & A are constants obtain the general solution in an explicit form  but how here we changed arbitrary constant C by Sin(A) although Sin(A) can not give the general solution since its range lies between negative one and one.

Comment: Could you put the ODE?

Comment: If $A$ is an arbitrary real constant, then $C=\sin A$ is an arbitrary constant in the range $-1 \le C \le 1$, yes. And that should be stated explicitly. But it would be easier to answer if we could see with our own eyes what is actually written in your book...

Answer (score 0):

Well, does it look stupid if I say that a constant is ... a constant ?

Let us consider $$I=\int \cos(t) dt$$ The solution is $$I=-\sin(t)+C$$ But, for  $$J=\int_a^x \cos(t) dt$$ the solution is $$J=\sin(a)-\sin(x)$$

The same kind of things can happen in differential equations because of the initial values. Consider the case of $$y'=\cos(x)$$ without any conditions or with the condition $y(0)=b$.

There could be other reasons and I suggest you add to your post an example from your book. We shall then try to explain why.

Comment: i will try to upload a picture but i mean how we restrict the constant and give the general solution , i mean can we say after that substitution we really obtained the general solution of the ODE ?